# Eclipse doesn't recognize my phone version

Tags: android, eclipse

When  I try to run  my android project in eclipse, my phone shows up...but not the version or anything else. It's like it doesn't recognize it fully. Here's a screenshot

[image]

Any suggestions? I have usb debugging enabled on my phone and have the correct drivers for the phone downloaded from motorola's website. I have the droid 2 global.

Comment: Have you tried to reset adb ?

Comment: I have not. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Go to DDMS view in eclipse and in the left panel click on the down arrow and reset adb

Comment: hmn.. I get a connection error when trying to do that. Could that be my problem with detecting my device as well? This is the exact error: Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Plug/unplug the device when reset...

Comment: I get the same error message. I took my phone out when I reset the adb , still got the same message.

Comment: Ok...I have no idea how, but it just started working. lol....silly eclipse. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset ADB and unplug/plug your device until it works ;)

Comment: I have also found that sometime certain usb connectors will cause that issue with my phone (HTC desire HD).

Answer (score 0):

Take command prompt.
Change the directory to /android/platform-tools/
Run the following command and see whether your phone is being detected by ADB

```
$adb devices
```

If you can't find your phone, try uninstalling the driver and installing the driver using PdaNet. Also do update the Android SDK and make sure you have installed the Google USB drivers in it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

it worked for me.